# SQL query for records based on columns value

Tags: sql, teradata

I have two tables joining, I am looking to query records that have more than 3/three pmt_cde within last 60 days

```
TABLE1:
 ID_CHAIN
 PMT_CDE
 PMT_DATE
 PMT_AMOUNT
```

and

```
TABLE2:
 ID_CHAIN
```

I am looking for ID_CHAIN that has more than 3 of PMT_CDE = 536 in last 60 days.

P.S. this is a new question, I had a similar case earlier today but trust me this is totally new. Thanks.

Comment: which database are you using?

Comment: ... they might be different, but the change from the answers to your previous question is ridiculously trivial.  You're getting into date math, which is RDBMS dependent, so you'd have to specify vendor/platform/version.  what does your current attempt look like?  Probably you'll need to add the condition in two places.  Why didn't you include this information in your previous question?  You would benefit greatly from reading the documentation and experimenting.

Comment: Why is `TABLE2` necessary for this question?

Answer (score 1):

Since you haven't specified which RDBMS - this is an Oracle answer (but it should be relatively simple to translate the date arithmetic to any other RDBMS):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5e390e/4)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (
  ID_CHAIN    NUMBER,
  PMT_CDE     NUMBER,
  PMT_DATE    DATE,
  PMT_AMOUNT  NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ( 1, 536, DATE '2015-07-23', 0 );
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ( 1, 536, DATE '2015-07-22', 0 );
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ( 1, 536, DATE '2015-07-21', 0 );
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ( 1, 536, DATE '2015-07-20', 0 );
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ( 2, 536, DATE '2015-07-22', 0 );
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ( 2, 536, DATE '2015-07-21', 0 );
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ( 2, 536, DATE '2015-05-01', 0 );
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ( 3, 536, DATE '2015-07-22', 0 );
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ( 3, 536, DATE '2015-07-21', 0 );
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ( 4, 536, DATE '2015-02-03', 0 );
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ( 4, 536, DATE '2015-02-02', 0 );
INSERT INTO TABLE1 VALUES ( 4, 536, DATE '2015-02-01', 0 );
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT ID_CHAIN
FROM   TABLE1
WHERE  PMT_DATE >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '60' DAY
AND    PMT_CDE  = 536
GROUP BY ID_CHAIN
HAVING COUNT(ID_CHAIN) > 3
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5e390e/4/0)**:

```
| ID_CHAIN |
|----------|
|        1 |
```

Comment: Teradata appears to use ANSI SQL 2008 - the updated query runs in Oracle but should be to the same standard and may be portable. Try it and see - otherwise work out what's broken and post back.